# Uses of Neither.....nor

Tags: grammaticality, conjunctions, neither-nor

"The interior of the earth can be understood only by indirect evidences as neither any one has nor any one can reach  the interior of the earth."

This is a excerpt [Fundamentals of Physical Geography, Chapter 3, p.18](https://ncert.nic.in/textbook.php?kegy2=3-16)

In above sentence,I think, it should be 'neither any one has reached'. Because later 'reach' is present simple and have been used with modal.

Is the above sentence grammatically right?

Comment: It's very badly written.

Comment: 'This is _an_ excerpt _from_ a book.' (What book?)  It would be much more natural to say **No-one either has [reached] or can reach the interior of the earth.**

Comment: 'Fundamentals of physical geography' ncert book.

Comment: I think the moral here is not to use geography books to learn English!

Comment: The publisher needs to engage better proof-readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in your interpretation. We need to insert **reached** after the auxiliary verb *has*.

> The interior of the earth can be understood only by indirect [evidence] as neither [anyone] has **reached** nor (anyone) can reach the interior of the earth."

The *reach* after *can* is called the bare form of the verb.

Also it should be **anyone**, and the second of which is optional.

Please note too that *evidence* is noncount.